# Copying slides from one Powerpoint Presantation to another with Powershell

Tags: powershell, powerpoint

I would like to copy a slide from one Powerpoint Presantation to another with Powershell.
Could anyone help me?

Here is my code which doesn't work:

```
Add-type -AssemblyName office

$npath = “C:\p3.pptx"
$test = Test-Path $npath 
if($test = $true){Remove-Item $npath }

$ppo = New-Object -ComObject powerpoint.application 

$p1 = “C:\p1.pptx"
$p2 = “C:\p2.pptx"

$pp1 = $ppo.Presentations.open($p1)
$pp2 = $ppo.Presentations.open($p2)

$pp2.Slides.item(54).copy()
$pp1.Slides.item(54).paste()

#I have tried it too, but it doesn't work:
# $cs = $pp2.Slides.item(54)
# $pp1.Slides.item(54).copy($cs)

$pp1.Saveas($npath)
$pp1.Close()
$pp2.Close()

$ppo.quit()
$ppo = $null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this method :

```
$pp2.Slides.InsertFromFile($p1,54,54,54)
```

Syntax : 
FileName:=“C:\p1.pptx", Index:=54 (in the new ppt), SlideStart:=54, SlideEnd:=54

No need for copy and paste.

Comment: If you want to replace instead of add, you can delete the slide like this :
$pp2.Slides.Item(x).Delete()

Comment: Is there a way to do this without com?